# zuul 2 with spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, url-routing, netflix-zuul

I was doing routing POC with zuul in spring boot (by enabling zool proxy @EnableZuulProxy). spring-cloud-starter-zuul uses zuul1. Also zuul2 is released. I know that spring has not provided support of zuul2.

Is there any way by which I can add zuul2 in spring boot?. Add dependency of zuul2 in project and register filter and router capability that it provides in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot is not going to integrate Zuul 2 ( Zuul 2 right now runs as its own bootstrap). Spring has introduced a spring cloud gateway rather than support Zuul 2.